# Have robot(wheeled) the move to creates a 2d maps

Tags: ros, imu, robot, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi have robot(wheeled) the move to creates a 2d maps  the robot has imu encoder and ultrasonic sensors and Arduino till now i only know how to to move the robot by pub | sub but I don't know what to do next can u help me please what do i have to learn next?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396073/have-robot(wheeled)-the-move-to-creates-a-2d-maps/) by [Midorya](https://answers.ros.org/users/91300/midorya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For mapping the environment you would need a Lidar,for tutorials on mapping and navigation you can start from ROS Navigation Stack - http://wiki.ros.org/navigation also a nice tutorial of real mapping bot - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1u_cC-5Sac

---

Originally posted by [harshmahesheka](https://answers.ros.org/users/96744/harshmahesheka/) with karma: 26 on 2022-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Midorya](https://answers.ros.org/users/91300/midorya/) on 2022-03-02**:
thanx bro♥